# Count Relational Table Entries

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='id, name, count(events.id) AS event_relational';
$criteria->with=array('events');
$model = Profiles::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Response:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Profile 1","event_relational":"0"}]
```

---

Code 2:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='id, name';
$criteria->with=array('events');
$model = Profiles::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Response 2:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Profile 1","event_relational":null},{"id":"2","name":"Profile 2","event_relational":null}...]
```

---

---

When I use COUNT the query stop in the first MySQL entry.
I would like to the code return all entries and check if have relational event.

Response that I want:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Profile 1","event_relational":"0"},{"id":"2","name":"Profile 2","event_relational":"1"}...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you will need to `group` by the `profile.id` :

```php
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='id, name, count(events.id) AS event_relational';
$criteria->with=array('events');
$criteria->group='t.id';
$model = Profiles::model()->findAll($criteria);
```